# Azure Data Lake - Data Security and Compliance

Tags: azure-data-lake

If the data in the Azure Data Lake is deleted, is the data fully deleted and non-retrievable?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately yes, thought it might have asked to create a backup. Try restoration. Always works

Comment: It's always a good idea to quote from the official docs if possible.